Converting sfdt to docx
I need to replace some of the content in a sfdt / docx file.
I have keywords that I replace but an sfdt object has the "tlp" key-value that contains the text.
But sometimes the text gets split between several tlps.
If anyone has any idea how can I do that without converting the sfdt json to a docx I would be glad.
Also I would like to know if I can convert the sfdt to a docx file with Python.
